# Cant open anything in admin panel of magento after successfull login?

Tags: php, magento

i have just installed magento store, but when i am trying to add product and anything in admin panel this error displays.

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1564392442
Magento is a trademark of Magento Inc. Copyright © 2013 Magento Inc.

And in error report below detail is generated.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:71:"Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually";i:1;s:4124:"#0 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\lib\Zend\Cache\Backend.php(197): Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not deter...')
#1 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\lib\Zend\Cache\Backend\File.php(123): Zend_Cache_Backend->getTmpDir()
#2 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\lib\Zend\Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
#3 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\lib\Zend\Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('File', Array, false, false)
#4 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\lib\Zend\Locale\Data.php(314): Zend_Cache::factory('Core', 'File', Array, Array)
#5 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Html\Calendar.php(42): Zend_Locale_Data::getList('en_US', 'days')
#6 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Html_Calendar->_toHtml()
#7 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#8 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('calendar', true)
#9 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page\head.phtml(33): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('calendar')
#10 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('D:\EmpiricalEdg...')
#11 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#12 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#16 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\page.phtml(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#17 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(241): include('D:\EmpiricalEdg...')
#18 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml\defau...')
#19 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Block\Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#24 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Customer\GroupController.php(58): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#25 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Customer_GroupController->indexAction()
#26 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#27 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#28 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#29 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#30 D:\EmpiricalEdgeINC\Projects\Magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#31 {main}";s:3:"url";s:75:"/index.php/admin/customer_group/index/key/b2fae5e1d3af811ecf33afc28e846de0/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

How to solve this
please help

Comment: Did you try logging out, emptying cache and restarting the browser?

Comment: check this [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/57578/) looks like they have a similar issue

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem occurs due to permissions for the folders. Try to give 777 permissions to the "var" folder or else create a temp folder with a 777 permissions at your var folder.

```
Firstly, copy “/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php” to “/app/code/local/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php”.
```

**NOTE: If local folder is not available, create it..**

Then in the file which you have created recently and in that,

```
on line 91 or near this line, you will find:

    'cache_dir' => null,
    Change to:
    'cache_dir' => "var/tmp/",
```

Comment: if u want to add sample products after installation then you have to start your installation procedure once again.. That is the only way because magento creates all the empty tables if tables are not available in your db. After installation all the tables are get created. If you want the procedure, let me know..

Comment: On all my magento installations (up to v1.7.0.1) the cache folder is `var/cache`, inside of which Magento instantly adds numerous `mage--x` subfolders. Cache is 777 perms.